# Kernel Dihedral group

Tags: abstract-algebra, self-learning, group-homomorphism

I seek to find the kernel of the homomorphism $$\theta(g) = A^{-1}gA$$ from the dihedral group $$D_4$$ of order $8$ to itself. Where A is a fixed element of $$D_4$$

I know that the kernel consists of the element $g$ is such that $$A^{-1}gA =1$$ which would imply that $$g=AA^{-1}$$. Is this a specific group?

I also wanted to prove that it is injective so I took $$g_1, g_2$$ such That $$A^{-1}g_1A= A^{-1}g_2A$$ if I multiply by A on the left side and A inverse on the right I gEt that $$g_1 = g_2 $$ Is this correct?

Comment: What is $A$ (or, why is it capital)? Otherwise, yes, $\theta$ is injective.

Comment: I am assuming you mean that $A$ is some fixed element of $D_4$. In that case the kernel is trivial and your proof works. Also I would like to mention some general facts about group actions. Suppose $G$ acts on itself (for example by conjugation i.e $A\cdot g:=A^{-1}gA$ in your case). Then for a fixed $A\in G$, the action induces a bijection from $G\to G$. In your case the action is very special and the induced bijection also turns out to be a homomorphism.

Comment: Yes, as Arpan mentioned A is an element of D4.

Comment: An inner automorphism is bijective by definition.